# What is the name of data structure like list, but with round brackets in output?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, variables

I have three variables. I know names for the two first, but not for the last one.

**Code:**

```
somev1 = ['"Peter"','"20"'] # List
somev2 = ', '.join(somev1) # Just a string, that was joined from first list
somev3 = "Peter", "20" # I don't know

print(somev1) # Output : ['"Peter"', '"20"']
print(somev2) # Output : "Peter", "20"
print(somev3) # Output : ('Peter', '20')
```

Comment: It's called a tuple.

Comment: Tuples, check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuples). You should also note the difference between immutable and mutable.

Comment: `print(type(somev3))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`somev3 = "Peter", "20"` creates a `tuple` which is like a list accept it is not mutable.

It would be equivalent to:

```
somev3 = ("Peter", "20")
#or
somev3 = tuple(["Peter", "20"])
```